# Install R-Package IKTrading from Github - error message

Tags: r, windows, git

I allow myself to post this help request as my attempts to download the R package "IKTrading" from Github repeteadly failed. I used both R V. 3.1.3. and R V.3.2.1.with identical results.

My computer runs R on Windows 7, 64bit version. Here is the session status:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk" Copyright (C) 2015
The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Standard recommended solutions I found on the internet did not work in my case, such as:
- Running R as administrator (done)
- Making sure that that Rtools is already installed (done)
- Scrupulously respecting the order of execution of different R packages,
including more particularly devtools and quantstrat (done all that).

Here is the error message output for further investigation:

```
> install_github(repo="IKTrading", username="IlyaKipnis")
Downloading github repo IlyaKipnis/IKTrading@master
Installing IKTrading
Skipping 1 packages ahead of CRAN: PerformanceAnalytics
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Cédric  \
  Spahr/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkP2GeU/devtools15d04c2a1d0a/IlyaKipnis-IKTrading-0b4e0e5"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Cédric Spahr/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'IKTrading' ...
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Cidric Spahr/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/IKTrading/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'IKTrading'
* removing 'C:/Users/Cédric Spahr/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/IKTrading'
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
Username parameter is deprecated. Please use IlyaKipnis/IKTrading
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Installing package quantstrat as IKTrading package has dependency on it.

```
require(devtools)
install.packages("quantstrat", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(quantstrat) #Load package
install_github("IlyaKipnis/IKTrading")
```

If this doesn't work, try running RStudio as administrator and run these commands again. Let me know if it works !